# Customizing Spring Integration Web Service SOAP Envelope/Header

Tags: soap, spring-integration, spring-ws

I am trying to send a SOAP request using Spring Integration like

```
<int:chain input-channel="wsOutChannel" output-channel="stdoutChannel">
    <int-ws:header-enricher>
        <int-ws:soap-action value="..."/>
    </int-ws:header-enricher>
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway
            uri="..."/>
</int:chain>
```

but you can only add the SOAP body, and Spring Integration adds the envelope, header, and body tags like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            ...
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to customize the envelope and header tags with specific attributes, for example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
```

and child elements, for example:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <child>...<child>
<soapenv:Header>
```

Is this possible with Spring Integration Web Services, or should I not use `int-ws:outbound-gateway` and take a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ClientInterceptor` (via the `interceptor` attribute) which allows you to modify the request before it's sent out.

**EDIT**

@Artem's suggestion is simpler but the interceptor gives you access to the response too; but either way, the code is similar.

For the interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends ClientInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        SoapMessage request = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
        SoapEnvelope envelope = request.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addAttribute(new QName("foo"), "bar");
        SoapHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://fiz/buz", "baz"));
        return super.handleRequest(messageContext);
    }

}
```

For the callback version:

```
@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    SoapEnvelope envelope = ((SoapMessage) message).getEnvelope();
    envelope.addAttribute(new QName("foo"), "bar");
    SoapHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
    header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://fiz/buz", "baz"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you can inject `WebServiceMessageCallback`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="request-callback" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
Reference to a Spring Web Services WebServiceMessageCallback. This enables changing
the Web Service request message after the payload has been written to it but prior
to invocation of the actual Web Service.
                </xsd:documentation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                        <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback"/>
                    </tool:annotation>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

and cast the message to the `SoapMessage` and use its `getEnvelope()` to customize a desired way.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler - I added code to my answer for both techniques.